# Sign in with requests leads to "SSO Request Failed, Session token is null"

Tags: http, python-requests

I am trying to implement a solution of signing in and retrieving data similar to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module) However, when I send my get request, and print the text, I get the following:

```
{
  "errorCode" : "5011",
  "errorMessage" : "SSO Request Failed, Session token is null.",
  "errorMessageDetail" : null
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

My code:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
     r1 = s.post(url1,data={'username':'user_name','password':'1234','rememberme':'true','userprofile':'true'})
     r2 = s.get(url2, cookies=r1.cookies)
     print(r2.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I was using the wrong URL
2. Perhaps, I have run into one of the complex issues listed here: [How to login using requests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746226/how-to-login-using-requests-in-python)